# Android: Automatically Taking Pictures with different exposures

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm very new to android SDK, and I was wondering how easy it is to do what I ask in the title, I want to write an app which uses the default camera app to take a picture with different exposures (so with one button user will take 5 pictures (exposure: -4, -2, 0, +2, +4))

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to set the exposure compensation you need to be able to get a hold of a [`Camera`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) object in order to obtain the parameters and then call the [`setExposureCompensation(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setExposureCompensation%28int%29) method. However, this is not possible by simply using the default camera app ([which is shown here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intent-image) by using intents).

In order to accomplish this goal you will need to [build a custom camera app](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera), which is no small task. It is a lot of fun though if you're ready for the ride!

Comment: Hi Daniel, Than you for your answer, I'll definitely check on the link you sent me.

Comment: Your question is a little broad, so you might want to consider researching the links I included, and ask some more focused questions once you get further down the path of building the app. Bottom line: this cannot be done with the default camera app being launched from your app. You will need to build an android camera app. Consider marking the question answered once you get a chance to read over the links if you find them helpful.

Comment: I'm reading the links right now, your answer is very helpful indeed, I haven't marked it as answered because while I'm reading the links, I want to give the other users a chance to take a look at the question and see their suggestions as well :)

Comment: I'm marking it as answered now, Thanks again for your answer! Looks like I'm going to have to create my own camera app.

Comment: No pressure! I just noticed that you were new here so I figured I'd give you a lil' nudge :)